# Is it possible to only have the admin interface bind to the local loopback?

Tags: security

I was wondering if it's possible to bind only the admin interface (and not the page) to the local loop back address?

For purposes of keeping the wrong people off the administrator interface with SSH.

Comment: and how will that help you? you are not likely to admin wp from the server it is running from

Comment: You are if you use SSH port forwarding.

Comment: how do you use port forwarding with a browser, and does it make a real difference? if you want an admin to be on a different port it makes probably more sense

Comment: @MarkKaplun when you port forward, you have a port on your computer, which you point your browser at on 127.0.0.1:<local-port> and you have a port that has been forwarded by SSH on the Wordpress machine (but bound to the localhost address on the Wordpress machine) and when you type that local port and ip on your local machine it goes through the tunnel to the remote port on the wordpress machine and brings you back your admin interface;

Comment: So unless you're logged into the Wordpress machine from a keyboard that is is plugged into it; unless you have an SSH connection with the port forwarding, you won't see the port for the admin console.

Comment: ok, maybe there is some sense, but IMO not worth the trouble. Anyway, just limit access to the wp-admin directory to the local ip like any other ip based access limitation in htaccess

Comment: IIRC on of the SSL variations supports letting the server identify the  client, which is basically what you are recreating. Maybe it is worth your time to investigate that direction

Comment: What does IIRC stand for?

Comment: If I Remember Correctly